# VPN - split tunnel routing

Tags: network, vpn

I would like to use a VPN to access all sites external to our local intranet, but preserve local routing so that I can still access sites on the local intranet (e.g. in 10.0.0.0/8). I am using the Mac OS X native L2TP VPN client. How do I configure it to set this up?

I have tried something like `route add 10.0.0.0/8 [local router address]`, which works fine, but I would like to automate this process so I don't have to look up the local router address and run the command each time.

Answer (score 0):

The Split Tunneling Set is done by the Server (VPN Concentrator) in your Company. This is the common setup. Most of the Cases you want to surf the web and this works over the vpn tunnel if you are connected. In my Company we have to use the proxy of the intranet during the vpn connection. Anyway it is not possible from the client side automatically. But if you use a proxy in the intranet, you can configure this in the properties of the vpn tunnel.

Comment: This is only true in some specific cases (usually with corporate VPNs using Cisco IPsec). This is not the case here, and I don't believe that this is not possible to do automatically given that it is possible to be done manually. There is no proxy available.