# VPN client software for macOS which allows for split tunnelling incoming SSH connections

Tags: macos, network, software-recommendation, ssh, vpn

As @bmike explained in [Cannot connect to Mac (Big Sur) running SSH server while connected to VPN](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415648/cannot-connect-to-mac-big-sur-running-ssh-server-while-connected-to-vpn) a VPN client allowing for split tunnelling is required in order to connect to a host via SSH which has an VPN client running. The PIA client offers this [feature](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/kb/articles/desktop-application-split-tunneling-feature) but requires application bundles to be added to the list of applications exempt from VPN. Unfortunately `sshd` is a mere binary, not an application bundle.

Are there VPN clients for macOS which would allow me to configure split tunnelling for incoming SSH connections?

Comment: To be clear, opting an app (or list of apps) to listen locally for incoming connections doesn’t enable split tunneling in general (which is what ssh needs). It pokes a small hole in a tunneling setup. Any vpn can allow ssh with a configuration change (including your current VPN client). I suppose you’re asking for a client to lie to the server and  say the tunnel isn’t split when it goes ahead and splits the tunnel.

Comment: Maybe I still don't quite get it: I do want to SSH to my public (non-VPN) address. I want the running VPN client to ignore this traffic. I want it to not route the SSH response packets back through VPN but back just the way they came in.